# Simplifying $\Big[\dfrac{5-\sqrt{a}}{5+\sqrt a}-\dfrac{\sqrt a+5}{\sqrt a-5}+2\Big]^{-2}$

Tags: problem-solving

Simplifying $$\Big[\dfrac{5-\sqrt{a}}{5+\sqrt a}-\dfrac{\sqrt a+5}{\sqrt a-5}+2\Big]^{-2}$$ 
When I try, the numerator cancels out to $0$, yet the answer sheet says $(25-a)^2/10000$. Where am I going wrong & how is getting $10 000$ there even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the expression in the brackets can be adapted by changing the sign of the second term and the signs in the denominator. Simplify to  $$\frac {5-\sqrt a}{5+\sqrt a}+\frac {5+\sqrt a}{5-\sqrt a}+2=\frac {(5-\sqrt a)^2+(5+\sqrt a)^2+2(25-a)}{25-a}=\frac {100}{25-a}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $s = \sqrt{a}$:
$$
\frac{5-s}{5+s}-\frac{s+5}{s-5}
= \frac{-(s-5)^2 - (s+5)^2}
       {(5+s)(5-s)}
= \frac{(s-5)^2 + (s+5)^2}
       {s^2-5^2}
= \frac{2s^2 + 2 \cdot 5^2}{s^2-5^2}
= \frac{2(a + 25)}{a-25}
$$

Can you finish the problem?

Answer (score 0):

$$\dfrac{\bar w}w + \dfrac{w}{\bar w}+2\, =\, \dfrac{(\bar w+ w)^2}{\bar w w}\, =\, \dfrac{10^2}{25-a}\ \ \ {\rm for}\ \ \ \begin{align}w\, =\, 5+\sqrt a\\ \bar w \,=\, 5-\sqrt a\end{align}$$